# How to un-append 600 pictures from a now single file?

Tags: windows, command-line, pictures

Just copied about 600 pictures into a folder that didn't exist, expecting Windows to create the folder:

```
copy *.jpg C:\2jpg
```

Now I have a single file containing all the pictures.  How can I separate this file back into individual pictures?

I've tried a lot of different attributes but this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that’s what happened? How big is the file?

Comment: @DanielB yeah that kind of thing can happen when the copy command doesn't know if the destination is a file or a directory.  Why don't you try it then you would see `C:\blah>copy *.jpg .\asdffd`

Comment: can't you copy them again? it'll be not that easy to split them up(though no doubt some could do it easily).. firstly the copy might not have combined them correctly, for that you need copy /b, and secondly it'd have to split by whatever bytes mark the beginning of a jpg file. it's probably easier to copy them again.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this question is because I lost the originals.
-
There is only one file with no file extension, in windows it looks like a white piece of tile. No it's not a word document, in the properties it states it's a file. just a 'File'
-
Might have exaggerated in pictures but it's 1.44mb of non-high res.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the originals, then the easiest would be to copy them over again the right way.

If you no longer have the originals, it might be easier to go back to the SD card and try some photo recovery tool such as [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to get them; however, if the SD card has been used since the files were copied off, then there's the chance that the file data have been overwritten.

If you truly want to split the single file you have, you could probably use PhotoRec on the file itself to get it to detect the JPEG files inside it.

I never used it on Windows if it's even available, but worst case you could boot a Linux live CD such as Ubuntu or Trinity Rescue Kit, quickly install PhotoRec if it isn't already available (something like "sudo apt-get install photorec" or "sudo apt-get install testdisk"), and then run the tool from there.

From what I recall, the PhotoRec tool will probably require admin/root access if you're working from physical media such as a hard drive or SD card, but if you just have your "2jpg" file, then you should be able to run it as an ordinary user.

It'll go through your 2jpg file and dump all files it can recognize into separate, individual files.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you used the [`COPY`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) command without the `/b` switch like:

```
copy /b *.jpg C:\a_large_file
```

you won't end up with a large file containing all the JPEGs. So make sure that the file you have does indeed contain all the JPEGs slammed into it.

If the size of the file you have isn't as large as you'd expect 600 JPEGs to be, you've lost your photos and there isn't much you can do other than try to salvage the original photos from the storage media using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or similar data recovery software.

However, just in case you ended up with a large file, you can use [binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) to [extract the JPEGs](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/issues/38):

```
binwalk --dd='jpeg:jpg' file.bin
```

However, **binwalk** doesn't work well on Windows, so I'd suggest using [Dragon UnPACKer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dragonunpacker/). What you want to use is the built-in **HyperRipper tool**.

1. Start the program and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or Select File → HyperRipper
   [image: HyperRipper]
2. Select `JPEG` from the **Formats** tab
   [image: HyperRipper formats]
3. Load the file in the **Search** tab and hit the Search button. When search is complete, click OK
   [image: HyperRipper load]
4. You should see the recovered JPEGs in the preview pane. Select the ones you want and extract them like so:
   [image: Extract JPEGs]

Comment: VERY USEFUL!!!
THANK YOU!
-
Unfortunally I ran with the same problem with only a few flash files, around 10 .sfw  Would you also happen to know the fix?

Comment: Could you be rephrase that? I didn't understand what you were trying to say. What problem did you run into and what do you mean by flash files and .sfw?

Comment: Copy *.sfw C:\sfw
Same problem but with flash files, just 10. Nothing worth fixing, bet is faster to find them than to fix the file composition.

Comment: The extension for Flash files is usually `SWF`. You can't use Dragon UnPACKer to extract SWFs because the Hyper Ripper component of DUP doesn't support detection/extraction of SWF. You probably can use `binwalk` for this purpose though.